# Optimizing A* pathfinding for multipe targets

Tags: c++, optimization, path-finding

I want to move some units from one place to another. When I move 2 or 3 units its no problem, but when I try to move 20 or 30 it takes a lot of time... Generally, the units move nearly same path, so I dont need to count it 20 times... I thought that I will cout the way from the first unit, and then just "add" the paths for rest of units (I mean that if we call the 1st unit's path P, it would be (Unit n -> P start) + P + (P end -> Unit n target) for unit n)... It worked great, but in some cases It makes very strange things, for expamle when 2nd unit is just near the target, it has to go to the 1st unit start and then back to the target... How can I optimize that? Maybe Its a good idea to divide units into groups and then move groups? I dont have ay better ideas...

Thanx for any help, sorry for my bad english and sorry for long, hard to read text...

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the path of the first unit?

Comment: @Beata Becouse otherwise I would have to compute it several times, and It would be just a bit different that the first...

Comment: Eh? If you can compute a path for the first unit, why not compute a different path for each unit? Why must they walk in each other's footsteps?

Comment: @Beata becouse pathfinding isnt very fast, and It would take a lot of time :/. I think you dont want 20 sec lag to move 100 units, huh?

Comment: How optimal is your A* algorithm? Is it multi-level (ie operate at macro level first, then at micro level through only the macro path)? If 100 units is taking 20 seconds, it sounds like you've got a very large graph to search through, which gives lots of room for this optimization.

Comment: Also, once you get this part optimized, a fun exercise is to avoid making every unit take the same path. It looks funny that way and if your units have collision detection it'll create huge clogs.

Add another dimension -- time -- and make each path account for all the other paths -- optimize for maximum throughput by balancing bandwidth and distance.

Answer (score 3):

A promising solution is *path caching*.

In particular, a shortest path, P, comprised of an ordered sequence of nodes X_0 to X_n has a lot of useful information.

Most importantly, for any i >= 0 and i < j <= n, the shortest path from X_i to X_j is a subsequence of the nodes in the path, P.

This gives you quite a lot of data (in fact, n^2 pieces of data) you can potentially re-use.

However, if your map is unchanging, it may be more practical to pre-compute the [all-pairs shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). This is an (extremely) easy algorithm to implement, but it takes O(n^3) time.

With all that said, it may make more sense for your A* implementation to simply maintain a hashtable of recent paths.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following to help.

1. Use path caching as noted earlier.  This may not pay off if your map is dynamic and forces the cache to clear often.
2. Use groups.  Treat a group of units as one, designate one as leader and find a path for it.   The other units can just follow the leader's footsteps with some minor path finding to those footsteps (so units appear to avoid obstacles in the main path too).  Pick units that are next to each other for this to work and the paths from the subordinates to the leaders should be really small.
3. Trade off accuracy for interactivity.  Don't calculate all of the paths at once, spread them out over time.  Use a priority queue for units needing paths, pop a few, calculate their paths.  You could even give your path finding code a time limit too.  I did this in Combined with grouping and path caching, this change in my implementation had the biggest gains for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1. Start the search at the common point of all searches: the target position.
2. Use the minimum distance over all units as A* heuristic, this is an admissible heuristic which results in optimal paths. It might get somewhat slow to compute with lots of units, you might have to do some tricks here
3. Do not restart the search after finding the first unit, just continue searching until you found all of them

You need to invert the directions of all "permissible move" checks because this is a backwards search, but other than that it probably works fine. Except that planning exact paths at the start of moving units is doing way too much work when it isn't even necessary yet, as long as the path doesn't look horribly stupid the player won't mind. And those exact paths frequently become invalid once you have consider other units blocking the paths.